# How to save Robot Framework tests' log files in release pipeline in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, robotframework, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have UI tests made by Robot Framework which we run after release in Azure DevOps. I can save test outputs, ie. passed and failed info. But how can I save logs, screenshots etc. outputs from those tests to release as files?

Comment: have you tried sending it though email after execution? (I am assuming you are using jenkins for execution)

Comment: Have you had a look at this [step-by-step guide](https://liftcodeplay.com/2017/11/13/how-to-use-robot-framework-selenium-tests-in-a-vsts-release-pipeline/)?

Comment: I am using Azure DevOps (the new name for Visual Studio Team Services). Primarily I'd like to save them to the release, not sending via email or saving them to Azure blob storage. Though I will try them if the first option can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

add below code in your yml file

```
 - task: PublishTestResults@2
    inputs:
      testResultsFiles: outputxunit.xml
      searchFolder: '/Users/runner/work/1/s/'
      condition: succeededOrFailed()
      displayName: 'Publish Test Results outputxunit.xml'
```